# Limit my website to loading only on specific devices

Tags: android

I would like to create a dashboard app/site running at my home(or maybe on my hosting plan online).  But the dashboard would display private info like locations of all family members, etc.  So I want to limit the site(or app) to only work on specific devices.  Ideally my wife and my Android phones.  I'm wondering if the Android app(or website) can check the device mac address and only work if the mac is in the white list?  Any other options for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need it to work for a small number of trusted users, which it sounds like is the case, you can simply generate a long, random string (too long to guess by brute force) and pass that in the URL to the site.  The server could then refuse to render the page for any request that doesn't pass the correct string.

This doesn't scale particularly well to more users, as the key could be leaked and you can't revoke access for one specific device, but for just you and your wife, it should be more than sufficient.